# How to check if entity is inside a list with RESTful APIs?

Tags: api, rest

I am designing the APIs for the backend of my app.

Suppose the user can follow the activity of another user.
In this case, I designed an API which allow me to do:

```
POST /me/following
```

and the id as body for this request.
Then I can retrieve the list of followers in this way:

```
GET /me/following
```

This API comes with pagination, so I cannot retrieve the entire list at once.
But how can I check if the user follows another user? Should I use something like

```
GET /me/following/{user_id}
```

and check the status code for this request? Like 200 it exists or 404 it doesn't exists in the list?

Usually 404 means the endpoint called doesn't exists. What if the entity doesn't exists? Is there a status code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET /me/following/{user_id}` seems good.

I would probably return a `204 No Content` :

> **Successful 2xx**
>   This class of status code indicates that the client's request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
>
> [...]
>
> 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation.

404 in contrast describes some kind of error, though it could do the job as well depending how you look at it

> **Client Error 4xx**
>
> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client
>   seems to have erred.
>
> 404 Not Found
>
> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No
>   indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or
>   permanent.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Ok but what if i am just checking if I'm (as user) following another user? For example suppose I just want to know if this user is in my following list. I would send a HEAD request (I don't need any info about the followed user). So if it is in the list I would except 204 since an HEAD request doesn't have a body. But if it is not in the list what would I except? 404? It's not an error from the client side is it?

Comment: Well I figured you would also want some details such as `followedSince`, in which case I wouldn't send a HEAD. Besides, I think most servers return 200 and not 204 for an OK HEAD. In any case, you can always use 404 if you want.

Comment: HTTP is never going to match your domain exactly, you have to make compromises and find the better suited HTTP idiom. There's often a good degree of freedom in this, it's not rocket science.

Comment: Nice I like that way. So a GET will return 200 with the user info in the list or 204 is the entity has not been found. As for HEAD, it will return 200 with no body if the entity is inside the list, and 204 if the entity is not inside the list. In this way I should be able to cover all cases. Thanks a lot!!